# "GDB не найден" при установке на Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, gdb, clion

При установке `Clion` на *Ubuntu 12.04* возникает следующая проблема: *GDB не найден*. Хотя на компе он есть.

Какой путь нужно указать в настройках `Clion` для *GDB*?

Comment: *ubuntu 12.04* — вероятно, слишком «древний» дистрибутив для «быстроживущих» проектов: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-740

Answer (score 1):

*ubuntu 12.04* — вероятно, слишком «древний» дистрибутив для «быстроживущих» проектов.

смотрите, например, обсуждение этой проблемы в баг-трекере: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-740